# Error opening new searcher. Solr Core init failures

Tags: solr, indexing

Our Solr for Sitecore is a master slave setup. Sitecore Solr slave has issues with the Sitecore analytics index and the error message is :

```
Error opening New Searcher. Core is missing.
```

We tried to look in to the error but could not gather much information on why this is happening.

We tried to fix the error but was not possible. We have the same index in master in perfect condition and is working fine. Can someone please help us in re-adding the Sitecore analytics index in Slave from scratch by using master's index?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the slave showing as running ok in the Sorl Admin UI? Also have you looked at the Solr/Catalina logs to see if there is anything showing in there?

What version of Solr and Sitecore are you using also?